# Create a list of lines representing the difference between two text files

Tags: python, text-files, diff

I have two text files. I want to find the percent difference between the two files based on different lines seen in the two files. I can use the number of lines in the list and then the number of lines of the two files to calculate the percent difference (unless there is some builtin python function that does this). For example

File 1:

```
apple
ball
cat
dog
```

File 2:

```
ball
cat
elephant
```

resulting list:

```
[apple, dog, elephant]
```

What would be the easiest and fastest way to do this?

Comment: I haven't used this, but it looks promising: [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "difference between two text files". Assuming that order doesn't matter to you and you just want to find lines from the two files that don't appear in the other, here is one possible solution:

```
set_1 = {line.strip() for line in open(file_1_path, 'r').readlines()}
set_2 = {line.strip() for line in open(file_2_path, 'r').readlines()}
difference = (set_1 | set_2) - (set_1 & set_2)
```

For sequence matching differences, you can [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) as suggested by [wjandrea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4518341/wjandrea). You can use it like this:

```
import difflib
list_1 = [line.strip() for line in open(file_1_path, 'r').readlines()]
list_2 = [line.strip() for line in open(file_2_path, 'r').readlines()]
difference = [line[2:] for line in difflib.ndiff(list_1, list_2) if line[0] in {'+', '-'}]
```